# Delete one by one the elements of a list, and then restore the previous ones

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, for-loop

I need it to extract the word that starts with a capital letter, if and only if, this word is preceded by the beginning of the sentence or by one of these options `(?:,and|and|her friends|,or |or |,)`

```py
import re

match_names = ""

input_sense = "Susan gave some cosmetic gifts to her friends Lisa, Veronica and Katy, but only Katy thanked her"

#I concatenate a series of characters that probably nobody uses so that it searches at the beginning
input_sense = "rlt99ll" + input_sense

if match := re.findall(r"(?:rlt99ll|,and|and|her friends|,or |or |,)\s*([A-Z].*?\b)", input_sense):
    match_names = match
    print("match names: ")
    print(match_names)

input_sense = input_sense.replace("rlt99ll", "") #I add this aux-string only for the pattern

n = 0
print("match_auxs : ")
for name in match_names:
    match_aux = match_names

    for m in match_aux:
        if (m == name):
            match_aux[n] = ""
        n += 1

    n = 0
    print(match_aux)
```

I need that output lists:

```
match names: 
['Susan', 'Lisa', 'Veronica', 'Katy']
match_auxs : 
['','Lisa', 'Veronica', 'Katy']
['Susan', '', 'Veronica', 'Katy']
['Susan', 'Lisa', '', 'Katy']
['Susan', 'Lisa', 'Veronica', '']
```

But I get this ( and it's wrong)...

```
match names: 
['Susan', 'Lisa', 'Veronica', 'Katy']
match_auxs : 
['', 'Lisa', 'Veronica', 'Katy']
['', '', 'Veronica', 'Katy']
['', '', '', 'Katy']
['', '', '', '']
```

Comment: `match_aux = match_names` doesn't make a copy of the list, use `match_aux = match_names.copy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, assigning a list to another variable doesn't create a copy of it. Along with this, your code can be simplified by using functions like `enumerate`:

```py
import re

match_names = ""

input_sense = "Susan gave some cosmetic gifts to her friends Lisa, Veronica and Katy, but only Katy thanked her"

#I concatenate a series of characters that probably nobody uses so that it searches at the beginning
input_sense = "rlt99ll" + input_sense

if match_names := re.findall(r"(?:rlt99ll|,and|and|her friends|,or |or |,)\s*([A-Z].*?\b)", input_sense):
    print(f"match names: {match_names}")

input_sense = input_sense.replace("rlt99ll", "") #I add this aux-string only for the pattern

n = 0
print("match_auxs: ")
for index, name in enumerate(match_names):
    match_aux = match_names.copy()
    match_aux[index] = ""
    n = 0

    print(match_aux)
```

If you don't want to use copy on the list (for speed), this code will also work:

```py
import re

match_names = ""

input_sense = "Susan gave some cosmetic gifts to her friends Lisa, Veronica and Katy, but only Katy thanked her"

#I concatenate a series of characters that probably nobody uses so that it searches at the beginning
input_sense = "rlt99ll" + input_sense

if match_names := re.findall(r"(?:rlt99ll|,and|and|her friends|,or |or |,)\s*([A-Z].*?\b)", input_sense):
    print(f"match names: {match_names}")

input_sense = input_sense.replace("rlt99ll", "") #I add this aux-string only for the pattern

n = 0
print("match_auxs: ")
prev = ""
for index, name in enumerate(match_names):
    if index > 0:
        match_names[index - 1] = prev
    prev = match_names[index]
    match_names[index] = ""

    print(match_names)
match_names[-1] = prev
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. Excuse me, do you know exactly why I can't copy the string like that?

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez you can, but copying the string might take longer and not be as efficient

Comment: *list of strings, not string